Covariance matrix as a “bilinear form”
Let $L^2(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{R})$ denote the space of finite variance real random variables on some probability space $\mathcal{P} = (\Omega, \Sigma, \mathbb{P})$. It is easy to see that the covariance, $\text{Cov}: L^2(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{R}) \times L^2(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is bilinear. And indeed, if we consider the linear map $A: L^2(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{R}) \longrightarrow L^2(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{R})$ given by $A(X) = X - \mathbb{E}[X] 1_\Omega$, where $1_\Omega: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is the constant map onto $1 \in \mathbb{R}$, we see that
$$\text{Cov}(X,Y)= \langle X, AY \rangle = \int_\Omega X AY d \mathbb{P}.$$
But now consider the space of square integrable random vectors $L^2(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{R}^n)$. Is there a way to view the cross-covariance matrix operator $\text{CovMat}: L^2(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{R}^n) \times L^2(\mathcal{P}, \mathbb{R}^n) \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ defined by
$$\text{CovMat}(X,Y) = \mathbb{E} \left [ (X - \mathbb{E}X) (Y - \mathbb{E}Y)^T  \right ]$$ as some analogue of a bilinear form? To be clear, $\mathbb{E}X$ and $\mathbb{E}Y$ are the $n$-vectors of component expectations. Clearly it’s not literally a bilinear form, as it’s not real valued. But it has a lot of bilinear-form-esque properties. It’s both $\mathbb{R}$-bilinear and $\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$-bilinear. However, the inner product seems like it’s been replaced with an outer product.
Is there a canonical interpretation of the cross-covariance matrix as some bilinear-form-like operator? In particular, The fact that Cov is a bilinear form lets us study covariance by studying the linear operator $A$. For example, this makes studying the derivative $\frac{d}{dX} \text{Cov}(X,X) = \frac{d}{dX} \langle X, AX \rangle$ easy. Is there an analogous tool for studying the derivative of the covariance matrix $\frac{d}{dX} \text{CovMat}(X,X)$?
Another interesting connection would be how covariance induces standard-deviation as a semi-norm. Is there some matrix valued semi-norm coming from the cross-covariance?
